# Duplicating magento for testing . Where to host?

Tags: magento2, testing, duplicate

I have a Magento website running and I need to run some tests on a duplicate magento website.

Duplicating website process is fine, however I wanted to know where people duplicate their website?

I saw people duplicating the website within a subdomain which is terrible for SEO and not a good idea.

I also tried hosting the website on a different port on my local ip but I am having some issues with ssl/nginx since it is a local site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicating your website within a subdomain is a good solution, you just need to configure the robots.txt file to forbid the indexation for the SEO.

You can also make your website private with the combo htaccess/htpasswd or a module that force login (and remove the ability to create an account) for a better access control.